# Loading random background music and displaying title

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently writing a script to play random mp3 files on the local server, and display the title at the top of the screen. However, it doesn't seem to work, at all.

Below some code has been removed, but these are the scripts I'm using to randomly pick a song and then display the title, any suggestions?

```html
<?php

// A Steam API Key is required so as to be able to contact steam and get a users profile image and name
// You can get a Steam API Key by visiting http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey
// Don't worry about the web address, it won't have any effect so just type in any web site
// Once you have your steam API Key simply paste the key below. (Make sure the quotation marks are still there or else it won't work)
$SteamAPIKey = "removed";


// Don't edit any of the PHP stuff here or else you may break the script
// If you website isn't displaying correctly then please make sure you have configured your loading url correctly
if (!isset($_GET["steamid"])) {
 die("Woops, you don't seem to be using the correct loading URL format, please make sure it has the correct extension it should look like this: www.yourdomain.com/loading/index.php?steamid=%s");
}

$steamid64 = $_GET["steamid"];

$url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=" . $SteamAPIKey . "&steamids=" . $steamid64;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$table2 = json_decode($json, true);
$table = $table2["response"]["players"];

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
    <!-- Hello, your reading the source code for the server load page -->
 <!-- Created by CaptainMcMarcus for CoderHire -->
    <!-- This is the HTML code below and is safe to edit to your needs -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

 <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Crystal Load - Crystal Blue Persuassion!" /> <!-- Webpage Description --> 
 <title>Crystal Load</title> <!-- Webpage Title -->
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <!-- Links to the Stylesheet -->
    <link href="colour.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <!-- Links to the Stylesheet for main colours -->
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script><!-- Link to jquery so we can do cool stuff -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/cycle.js"></script><!-- For Rotating Backgrounds -->
    
    <script type="text/javascript"><!-- Script to center content -->
 $(document).ready(function() {
  //Changes volume of song. 0.5=50% volume
  $('.audio').prop("volume", 0.5);
   
  //Perfectly centres content to the middle of the screen both vertically and horizontally
  $(window).resize(function(){
     $('.core-wrapper').css({
      position:'absolute',
      left: ($(window).width() 
     - $('.core-wrapper').outerWidth())/2,
      top: ($(window).height() 
     - $('.core-wrapper').outerHeight())/2
     }); 
  });
  // Initiate centre function
  $(window).resize();
  
  //Lets get thos backgrounds moving
  $('#background-scroll').cycle({ 
   fx: 'fade',
   pause: 0, 
   speed: 1800, //Time to fade into the next image [in milliseconds]
   timeout: 3500  //Time spent on image [in milliseconds]
  });
 });
    </script>
    

 </head>
 
 <body>
    
    <div id="background-scroll"><!-- Add Backgrounds so we can have multiple ones -->
     <!-- IF YOU NEED LESS BACKGROUNDS JUST REMOVE THEM OUT OF THE LIST -->
        <!-- TO ADD EXTRA BACKGROUNDS YOU NEED TO MODIFY THE STYLESHEET [ADVANCED USERS ONLY] -->
     <div id="bg1"></div><!-- BG 1 -->
        <div id="bg2"></div><!-- BG 2 -->
        <div id="bg3"></div><!-- BG 3 -->
        <div id="bg4"></div><!-- BG 4 -->
        <div id="bg5"></div><!-- BG 5 -->
        <div id="bg6"></div><!-- BG 6 -->
    </div>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 var s;
 s = this.number;
  function Name(){
   
    if (number == (1)){
     
     s = "Tobu - Candyland"
    }
    if (number == (2)){
     
     s = "Tobu - Colors"
    }
    if (number == (3)){
     
     s = "Tobu - Dreams"
    }
    if (number == (4)){
     
     s = "Tobu - Seven"
    }
    if (number == (5)){
     
     s = "Tobu - Such Fun"
    }
  }
 
 
 </script>
 
 <script>
document.write('<div id="'+s+'" ></div>');
</script>
    
    <div class="core-wrapper"><!-- Opens the wrapper so we can contain and center everything -->
     
        <img src="images/logo.png" width="960" height="120" alt="Your Logo" /><!-- This adds in the logo, simply change logo.png to make this look different -->
  
  
    
     <div id="left-items"><!-- Opens the wrapper for the left content, there isn't really much to change on the left side as it's dynamic -->
    
   <?php
    //PHP Code for the avatar display, it's probably best to leave this section alone
    echo "<div id=\"profile-wrap\">";
     
     //Add in the players avatar
     echo "<div id=\"profile-top\">";
      echo "<div id=\"avatarimg\">";
  //     echo "<img src=\"" . $table["avatarfull"] . "\" />";
      echo "</div>";
     echo "</div>";
     
     //Adds in the players name
     echo "<div id=\"profile-bottom\">";
   //   echo "<p>" . $table["personaname"] . "</p>";
     echo "</div>";
     
    echo "</div>";
            ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            
            
            <div class="title server">
             <h2>Server</h2><!-- Adds in the server title, you can change the text to be whatever you would like -->
            </div>
            
            <!-- Lets get the server Details in here -->
            <ul id="server-list">
             <li><img src="images/server-name.png" alt="Server Name" /> <span id="s-name">Server Name</span></li><!-- Dynamically adds the server name -->
                <li><img src="images/server-mode.png" alt="Game Mode" /> <span id="s-mode">Server Game Mode</span></li><!-- Dynamically adds game mode name -->
                <li><img src="images/server-map.png" alt="Map Name" /> <span id="s-map">Server Map Name</span></li><!-- Dynamically adds map name -->
            </ul>
            
      </div><!-- Close The Wrapper for the Left Items -->
        
        <div id="right-items"><!-- Open wrapper for the items on the right -->
         
            <div class="title">
             <h2>Staff</h2><!-- Adds in the rules title, you can change the text to be whatever you would like -->
            </div>
            
            <!-- Let's add in all the rules, the number inside the <span></span> tags will appear in a brighter coloured box  -->
            <ul id="rules">
             <li>Owner: Kaydax</li>
                <li>Owner: Name</li>
                <li>Co-Owner: Oilysgtjohnson</li>
                <li>Staff Director: UnknownKury</li>
            </ul>
            
       </div><!-- This close the right content wrapper -->
        
        <div class="clear"></div><!-- This clears things up so that we can vertically align things correctly -->
        
        <!-- This adds in the progress bar -->
        <div id="bar">
         <div id="bar-width" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- This adds in the progress percentage bar -->
        <div id="percentage">
         <p></p>
        </div>
        
        <!-- This adds the current item being downloaded, we use the word connecting by default because if we don't download anything then it won't change -->
        <div id="download-item">
         <p>Connecting...</p>
       </div>
    
    </div><!-- now we close the core wrapper to keep everything nicely contained and in the middle -->
    
    <!-- MUSIC SCRIPT -->
    <!-- To activate simply delete the comment tags and replace music.mp3 with the path to your sound file. -->
    <!-- Adding copyrighted music is illegal as you will be redistributing from the server this is hosted from, this means that you will be held liable -->
    
<script type="text/javascript">

var number;

function PlayIt(mp3){
 nummp3 = 5 
 day = new Date()
 z = day.getTime()
 y = (z - (parseInt(z/1000,10) * 1000))/10
 x = parseInt(y/100*nummp3,10) + 1
 if (x == (1)){
  mp3=("Candyland.mp3") }
 if (x == (2)){
  mp3=("Colors.mp3")
 }
 if (x == (3)){
  mp3=("Dreams.mp3")
 }
 if (x == (4)){
  mp3=("Seven.mp3")
 }
 if (x == (5)){
  mp3=("SuchFun.mp3")
 }
 document.getElementById('music').innerHTML='<object width="300" height="44" '
     +'classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" '
       +'codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701" '
       +'<param name="url" value="'+mp3+'">'
       +'<param name="uiMode" value="full">'
       +'<param name="autoStart" value="true">'
       +'<param name="loop" value="true">'
  +'<param name="volume" value="100">'
       +'<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" '
       +'pluginspage="http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/" '
       +'showcontrols="true" uimode="full" width="300" height="44" '
       +'src="'+mp3+'" autostart="1" loop="true">'
  +'<\/object>';
 alert(mp3);
 number = x;
}
window.onload=PlayIt;
</script>
</head>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script><!-- Script to get downloads, map, players, game mode and sort out the loading bar -->

 </body><!-- Closes off the HTML Document -->
</html>
```

Comment: Start by opening the console (F12), see what errors there are, and fix them one by one (there's several syntax errors.)

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shown doesn't do a thing, making it hard for us to debug. One thing you should avoid is using a keyword Number as a variable name. Here's a simple random songname picker:

```js
var songlist = ["Tobu - Candyland", "Tobu - Colors", "Tobu - Dreams", "Tobu - Seven", "Tobu - Such Fun"];

alert(songlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * songlist.length)]);
```

Comment: You use `number` in your first block, yet you define it in the second. You should probably rewrite a few parts of that code. I gave you how to pick a random item from an array, use it to start playing the song and show its title.